# How to get ckeckbox selected value of each dynamically created checkbox android java

Tags: java, android

In my android application I have created checkboxes for each title heading. for example

students:

- Games
- studies

teachers:

- Games
- studies

The checkboxes Widgets are created dynamically:

```
for (int a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                cb[a] = new CheckBox(this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                param.leftMargin = 25;
                // param.topMargin = (a + 1) * (105 + add1 -sub);
                param.topMargin = add1;
                cb[a].setPadding(45, 20, 25, 5); // cb[a].setPadding(5, 23, 5,
                                                    // 5);
                cb[a].setLayoutParams(param);
                cb[a].setText(data[a].trim());
                layout.addView(cb[a]);
                // add = add + 25;
                // add1 = add1 + 15;
                add1 = add1 + 35;
            }
```

And its working fine but I want to get checkbox selected values of each title heading.

I don't understand how I can do this.

Comment: to better clarify your question add the code that checks the Check-boxes status

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly to get the selected value you only need to run `cb.isChecked()`
to get if the checkbox is selected or not. if i'm missing something please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a boolean array of the same length as the number of the headings you have, while dynamically adding checkboxes implement their onCheckChange listeners to edit their respective elements of the boolean array, e.g 5th dynamically edited checkbox will set array[4] to True when checked. and in the end u can easily check the array which will reflect the result perfectly. Hope It Helps